# Error while installing mscgen with macports. Error: Failed to install python27

Tags: installation, macports

I try to install mscgen but I have this error :

```
xxxxx-mac:bin xxxxx$ sudo port install mscgen
--->  Computing dependencies for mscgen
--->  Dependencies to be installed: gd2 xpm xorg-libXext xorg-libX11 xorg-libxcb python27 python27 xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto libxml2 xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXt xorg-libsm xorg-libice
--->  Building python27
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install python27
Log for python27 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: gd2 xpm xorg-libXext xorg-libX11 xorg-libxcb python27 python27 xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto libxml2 xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXt xorg-libsm xorg-libice
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Comment: Well what does it say in `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/main.log`? Also what version of OS X are you on?